# Time complexities combining

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o

Here's a pseudocode procedure that checks whether a list has any duplicates:

```
duplicates(a,n) {
    t = EmptyTree

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert(a[i], t)
    }

    if (isIn(EmptyTree, t))
        return true
    else
        return false
 }
```

a is the array being checked, n is the length of the array. insert and isIn both have time complexities O(log2n) (this being log to base 2). My question is, what would be the average case and worst case time complexity of the whole duplicates procedure? I'm thinking it should be O(log2n) for both as both insert and isIn have this time complexity, but what's throwing me off is the for loop as it calls insert for every element - does this mean the procedure will be O(n) instead, as that's the time complexity of the for loop?

EDIT: adjusted procedure

```
duplicates3(a,n) {
    t = EmptyTree

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert(a[i], t)

        if (isIn(EmptyTree, t))
            return true
    }

    return false
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `isIn(a[i], t)` instead? Also, I think this should be *before* the `insert` call, because it will just return immediately after the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every iteration through the loop in the duplicates function you perform the insert operation which is O(log n).

You go through the loop n times.

So you do a O(log n) operation n times bringing your final complexity to O(n log n). So, based on the information you have provided the best case, average case, and worst case are the same.

---

Looking at the duplicates3 function there is now this exit condition in the loop. It's not entirely clear what this condition does but if there is a case where it could exit the loop after just one iteration then your best case would be just one iteration through the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so would the average-case and worst-case time complexities be the same then? Also, I have an edit version I've added to my post - would this decrease the time complexity as only in the worst-case would the whole array have to be iterated through, or would it not matter as in the average-case half the array would be iterated through, resulting in O(n/2 log n) that's just simplified to O(n log n) (same as worst case)? I want to make sure I'm getting this right.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. For context, when a duplicate is found, an emptytree is inserted into the tree and isIn checks if it's there. It would therefore have to be at least 2 iterations but I get the point. Much appreciated.